Derivation of Berry Phase
I'm learning about Berry phase for a presentation and am working through Berry's original paper.
I can't quite make the connection between equation 4
$$
\dot{\gamma}(t) = i \langle n(\vec{R}) |\nabla_R |n(\vec{R})\rangle \cdot \dot{\vec{R}}(t)
$$
where and equation 6
$$
{\gamma}(C) = i \oint_C \langle n(\vec{R}) |\nabla_R |n(\vec{R})\rangle \cdot d{\vec{R}}
$$
Equation 4 is derived from postulating that another phase (other than from Hamiltonian evolution) exists, and if so then that phase will obey that form. He then essentially jumps to equation 6.
I assume there is some calculus relation or detail from the adiabatic approximation that I am not seeing, any ideas?

Please read this and take appropriate actions (also for all other questions).

Equation $(6)$ is just obtained by integrating $(4)$ along a closed loop $C$.

I believe I had some errors in my original post for equation 6, and have now been fixed. Is this still true? I don't see how the time derivatives are delt with.

@Hurricane Yes, it's still true. Do you remember how to compute a line integral? You first define a parameterized curve $\vec R(t)$ such that $\vec R(0)$ is the starting point and $\vec R(T)$ is the ending point (in this case, they are the same point, since the curve is closed). Then $\int \vec F(\vec R) \cdot \mathrm d\vec R \equiv \int_0^T \vec F\big(\vec R(t)\big) \cdot \dot{\vec R}(t) \mathrm dt$.
